# Algorithms: How do I sum O(n) and O(nlog(n)) together?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, big-o

I have the follow algorithm which finds duplicates and removes them:

```
public static int numDuplicatesB(int[] arr) {
    Sort.mergesort(arr);
    int numDups = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
            numDups++;
} }
    return numDups;
}
```

I am trying to find the worst case time complexity of this. I know mergesort is `nlog(n)`, and in my for loop I am iterating over the entire data set so that would count as `n`.
I am unsure what to do with these numbers though. Should I just sum them together? If I were to do that, how would I do it?

Comment: Side note: you could use a hash table to do this in O(n) depending on memory requirements.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
O(n) + O(n log(n)) = O(n log(n))
```

For Big O complexity, all you care about is the dominant term.  `n log(n)` dominates `n` so that's the only term that you care about.

Comment: Another way to think about this is to imagine your O(n) processing was really O(n log n), as though you did two independent sorts. Then you'd have 2 * O(n log n). But constants slough off, so you're back to O(n log n).

Comment: @Jonathan While that works in practice, it is very much true that O(n) is _not_ equal to O(n log(n)), so I wouldn't advise using that on a regular basis.

Comment: @Emrakul I had a professor use that same reasoning in my algorithms class many years ago. I agree it is less than ideal, but it can be used to justify dropping off non-dominant terms. Personally, I prefer using the T() justification: T1(n) < T2(n) so ignore T1(n).

Comment: @Emrakul actually I think the reasoning is theoretically sound as well as practical.  O(n) is a proper subset of O(n log(n)).  So if f(n) belongs to O(n) it also belongs to O(n log(n)).

Comment: It should be noted that when we say `f(n) is O(g(n))` what we're really saying is that the function `f is a member of the set of functions that grows at the rate of at most g(n) over the long term`. This means all members of `O(n)` are also members of `O(n*log(n))`. The `+` in expressions like `O(f(n)) + O(g(n))` actually refer to set union (which of you're really pedantic, you really should use ∪).

Comment: Another way to calculate this is to ask how many times do we do n. We do it log n times. If you add O(n) to that you do it (log n) + 1 times.

Comment: Another observation is that if f(N) is O(N), that means that there is some k0 and n0 such that for all n > n0, f(n)<k0n.  Likewise, if g(N) is O(NlgN) that means there exists some k1 and n1 such that for all n > n1, f(n) < k1 * (nlgn).  Those statements together mean that if n2 is larger than n0, n1, and then number 2, then for all n which are greater than n2, f(n)+g(n) < (k0n+(k1 * (nlgn)) < (k0+k1) * (nlgn).

Comment: @LieRyan: I think `O(f(n)) + O(g(n))` is not really a union.  Rather, it's the set `{ h(n) + k(n) : h(n) in O(f(n)), k in O(g(n)) }`. It happens in this case to equal the union, but in general it might not.

Comment: @LieRyan Originally, it is not set union, but set sum: `A + B = { a + b | a in A, b in B }`. It happens that for sets of the form `O(g(n))` this is the same as set union, as one of the sets is always a subset of the other, and they both are invariant to sums (i.e. A + A = A).  (Oops, Nate did write essentially the same).

Comment: Adding O(f) does not make sense. It is a set. You would have to write [this](http://i.imgur.com/bHUCTBy.png) which is obviously true.

Answer (score 59):

Let's reason our way through it and remember the definition of `O`. The one I'm going to use is for the limit at infinity.

You are correct in stating that you perform two operations with corresponding asymptotic bounds of `O(n)` and `O(nlog(n))` but combining them into a single bound is not as simple as adding the two functions. You know your function takes at least `O(n)` time and also at least `O(nlog(n))` time. So really the complexity class for your function is the union of `O(n)` and `O(nlog(n))` but `O(nlog(n))` is a superset of `O(n)` so really it is just `O(nlog(n))`.

Comment: +1 this should be the answer. It describes the answer more precisely using compsci terms.

Answer (score 6):

If you were going to set it out longhand it would look roughly like this:

Suppose the total time is: a n + b n log(n), where a and b are constants (ignoring lower order terms).

As n goes to infinity (a n + b n log (n)) / n log (n) -> a / log (n) + b -> b

So the total time is O(b n log(n)) = O(n log (n)).

Answer (score 2):

Start with the definition of O ():

O (n log n) means "less than C n log n, if n is large".

O (n) means "less than D n, if n is large".

If you add both, the result is less than C n log n + D n < C n log n + D n log n < (C + D) n log n = O (n log n).

In general, if f (n) > C g (n) for large n and some C > 0, then O (f (n)) + O (g (n)) = O (f (n)). And after doing a few cases using the definition of O (), you'll know what you can and can't do.

Answer (score 1):

The big O notation is defined as a set:

[image]

So [image] contains all functions that are - starting from some arbitrary large point [image] - always smaller than g.

Now, when you have a function that is in [image] and then execute another one that increases slower than g it is certainly increasing slower than 2g. So executing anything slower than g will not change the complexity class.

More formally:

[image: f, h \in \mathcal{O}(g) \Rightarrow (f+h) \in \mathcal{O}(g)]

You can easily prove that.

**TL;DR**

It is still [image: n log(n)]